# Mapping a a column of data frame to Another existing data frame DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython

I have a date frame named as - 'DictSeasonCode' which has 2 columns - 'progcode' & 'Season' and the data frame  has a SeasoncodeID attached with it which is a unique number to progcode and season Like -

Progcode   Season   SeasonID
ABM          2006       1
ABM          2007       2
DFG          2006       3
DFG          2008       4
XYZ          2010       5

I have another data frame named as 'Program' which has Progcode and season as its attributes but its a larger data frame with more than 1 values of the same progcode and season like  -

Progcode    Season
ABM          2006 
ABM          2006
ABM          2006
ABM          2007
ABM          2007
DFG          2008
DFG          2006
XYZ          2010
XYZ          2010

And i want to attach the Season code ID to the data frame , which should look like -

Progcode    Season   SeasonID
ABM          2006       1
ABM          2006       1
ABM          2006       1
ABM          2007       2
ABM          2007       2
DFG          2008       3
DFG          2006       4
XYZ          2010       5
XYZ          2010       5

Would really appreciate if i could have a solution , 
Thank you

Comment: This would be easier to answer with some actual code examples. Can you [edit] your question and a minimal code example with what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas database style [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)-ing:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['Progcode', 'Season'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much evert, it was exactly whwt i was looking for